# Is Haskell self defined?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

For instance, how is function application defined (' ')? Does that definition have to be within the parser/compiler itself, or can it be overridden in a custom script?

Comment: If you are asking if the Haskell compiler is written in Haskell: yes. Does the language syntax have to be implemented in the compiler? Yes.

Comment: So there would have to be a compiler _not_ written in haskell first then. What about the function application operator ( )? Is there a definition for that in Prelude or something?

Comment: i believe ghc was originally written in C and later moved over to haskell.  There is a haskell compiler named hugs that is written in C

Comment: For the general concept, see also [Bootstrapping (compilers)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Ghc has always been written in Haskell.   Before ghc could compile itself, it was compiled using hbc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Haskell is not defined metacircularly. It is defined by the haskell report: http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/

There is no pluggable haskell compiler that lets you dynamically override application. You can use template haskell, or you can parse haskell using haskell-src-exts and write your own interpreter, or you can use plugins: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/compiler-plugins.html